# actionListener doesn't work, but the method does

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I have tested my method to add a value to the database and it works fine. However, when I try to use the method as an actionListener in a command button it doesn't work. Could anyone please explain what it is I have wrong? This is the method:

```
public void addToNetwork() {

    MindmapNode currentNode = this.selectedNode;

    this.user.setConnections( this.user.getConnections() + "-" + currentNode.getLabel() );
    this.userConn = Arrays.asList(this.user.getConnections().split("-"));
    this.setUserdetails( this.user );
}
```

And this is the xhtml:

```
<p:mindmap value="#{mmBean.root}" style="width:100%;height:600px" id="mindmap">
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{mmBean.onNodeSelect}" immediate="true"      
         id="oneClick" oncomplete="options.show()"  />
/p:mindmap>            


<p:dialog widgetVar="options">

    <p:panelGrid  id="optionspanel" columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Add this user to your network?"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Add" update="mindmap" actionListener="#{mmBean.addToNetwork}" onclick="options.hide()" id="btnAdd"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

</p:dialog>
```

This is the method for onNodeSelect:

```
public void onNodeSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    MindmapNode node = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();
    this.setSelectedNode(node);
}
```

Note that I easily force the add when they click, but I want to offer the user a bunch of other options as well, eventually.

Could this be done by, say, setting a property within addToNetwork to being true when they click add? Basically I'm thinking of something like remoteCommand? I tried having the first command set a connect-property to true and then the remoCommand calling the method with an if loop to connect if that property was set to true. That didn't work.

I suspect the problem is telling with maintaining in the object which node is the selectedNode, but I'm not sure. Any help would be great!

Edit: The answer was to store the nodelabel in the database and then access it again from there. Quite simple, really. I think the object was being destroyed sometime between the selectedNode value being set and being called, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrary to the `action` method, the `actionListener` method must take an `ActionEvent` argument.

You have 2 options:

1. Use `action` instead.

   ```
   <p:commandButton ... action="#{mmBean.addToNetwork}" />
   ```
2. Add that argument, even though you never use it.

   ```
   import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

   // ...

   public void addToNetwork(ActionEvent event) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)

Comment: Thank you, that is quite a helpful link. I think I essentially know what I want to do, but I'm not sure how:

I want to store the 'select' event, so that I can transfer the information of which node was selected onto the options dialogue - currently when I click on a node it SHOULD call this.setSelectedNode but I think it isn't. If I could store it clientside, or the info of which node was clicked, that'd be way handier.

Comment: I fixed it! I realised the mistake I was making was assuming the object should store the variable - I suspect it was to do with the scope of the backing bean. Instead I added a field to the database to store what the clicked node was. Still, it would have been faulty anyway if you hadn't answered, and I doubt I'd have figured it out as quickly, as I wasn't properly understanding the flow of information. Thank you!